# What should I do if my image doesn't get rendered?

Tags: html, image

I'm working on a school project and the picture I chose doesn't want to load. I'm pretty new to programming so I don't understand why it is happening. It's never happened before.

[image: Picture showing broken picture icon]

```
<img class="dckep1" src="../K%25C3%25A9pek/dckep1.jpg">
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The picture you chose doesn't exist where you think it exists. Make sure that the folder you are trying to navigate to is in fact deployed one folder up from the one your HTML file is. Also ensure that the name of the folder is getting encoded correctly. There are a number of websites online that will decode URL percent-encoded strings.

Comment: This question gets asked over and over again all over the internet and the solution is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in the path `../K%25C3%25A9pek/dckep1.jpg` there isn't any image. You might want to fix that.

Comment: There certainly is a picture. I didnt write the path by myself, I selected it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1wn2qpj